# How to add a Navigation bar within a a Header that includes already a word

Tags: html, css, web, header

if you copy this code,for example in notepadd++ and open it with chrome, you can see a website that i have started to build. I want to add a Navigation bar in h2. But i already added a word called"Elektrotechnik " there. How can i add a navigation bar there that includes three other words on the right side of the H2 box?

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <link rel="Stylesheet"
    href="main.css"
       
   
</head>
<body>

 <div id="wrapper"> 
    
<header>
<h1>CrackTec GmbH</h1>
<h2>Elektrotechnik<h2>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        
    </ul>
</nav>
    
<main>
   

</main>

<aside>
    
</aside>

<footer>
    
</footer>

</div>  
    
</body>
```

```
enter code here
         header {

         width:  100%;
         height: 50px;
         background-color: #B8860B;
         
          }
        
         h1 {
         font-size: 50px;
         margin-top: 15px;
         color: white;
         padding-left: 100px;
         font-family: Arimo;
         }  
         
         h2 { 
         color: white;
         background-color: #556B2F;
         padding-left: 100px;
         margin-top: -39px;
         font-family: Arimo;
         }
```

Comment: You should have a look at CSS grid options. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp there is also flexbox grid https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you. My teacher said to me i should watch the grid system its pretty easy and useful. but i havent watched anything about it yet

Comment: Then you should get cracking! :) It's very important fundamentals in web development. You don't even have to "master" it to be like "gosh I'm so happy that I know this stuff", and once you master it, you're gonna be like "yeah I can totally make any design I want with ease".

Answer (score 0):

You could insert list items to your  list in such a way:

```
<header>
    <h1>CrackTec GmbH</h1>
    <div class="sub">
        <h2>Elektrotechnik</h2>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a>About</a></li>
            <li><a>Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Then use Flexbox to position your h2 and your list

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width:  100%;
    background-color: #B8860B;
}
   
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arimo;
    padding:1rem;
}  
    
h2 { 
    color: white;
    font-family: Arimo;
}         

.sub {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #556B2F;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:1rem;
}

li {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was easier than expected. I am sorry if my english grammar isnt good.